# Which solution is best for breaking from a loop on user input?

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement, console-application, user-input

I am currently learning programming and often I stumble upon tasks where you type into the console indeterminate amount of lines (each is a command that I have to filter out later in main with a switch or if-else statements) and at the end you type "END" to say that you will stop writing lines (often it results in end of the program but sometimes I have to print some final code). For the longest time I have used this solution to choose the needed selection:

```
while (true) {
    var input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
    if (input[0] == "END") break;

    switch (input[0]) {
        //Task specific cases
    }
}
```

but today I randomly had an idea. (After I did some research) I could add the "END" case in the switch statement using the word return. The only problem is that because my code is in main it automatically ends the program. The solution is to transfer the code to another method but is this solution better or is it a bit overcomplicated?

*Here is what the second solution looks like:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        Logic();
    //Other stuff to do, if the task requires it
}

public static void Logic() {
    while (true) {
            var info = Console.ReadLine().Split();

                switch (info[0]) {
                        case "END": return;
                        //Other task specific cases
                }
        }
}
```

**Sorry if the post is confusing to read, I am not very good with programming terminology.

Comment: Side note: `.ToArray();` is *redundant*, since `.Split(...)` returns `string[]`

Comment: If you anyway use Switch Case with the Input then having an END Case in switch is more elegant IMO.

Comment: `do { ... } while (info[0] != "END");`. I'm not a big fan of `while (true)` along with `break;` or `return;`

Comment: Thank you Dimitry, I didn't realise. It's a habbit.

Comment: Using do-while means I have to declare info outside of the loop and I like everything that is needed in the loop and not outside it to stay in the loop.

Comment: `while (shouldEnd) { ... case "END": shouldEnd = true; break; ...` ?

Comment: Again, using a variable in the while loop requires declaration of that variable outside of the loop and I am trying to avoid that. Tell me if I shouldn't.

Comment: @Syndamia why not ? This is way cleaner.

Comment: @Cid yeah, you are right, it's just because you will have to declare a variable outside of the loop and I like everything to be encapsulated in one place. I guess it's just a weird thing I like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another possible implementation:

```
 public static void Logic()
    {
        bool exit = false;
        do
        {
            var info = Console.ReadLine().Split();

            switch (info[0])
            {
                case "END":
                    exit = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (!exit);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the solutions, to use break or to return are correct, but have different behaviors. You can use the one that you find is better.

> The break statement is used to terminate the loop or statement in
>   which it present. After that, the control will pass to the statements
>   that present after the break statement, if available. If the break
>   statement present in the nested loop, then it terminates only those
>   loops which contains break statement.
>
> The return statement terminates the execution of the method and
>   returns the control to the calling method. It returns an optional
>   value. If the type of method is void, then the return statement can be
>   excluded.

You can read more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-jump-statements-break-continue-goto-return-and-throw/